# How to upgrade Spree from 2.2.6 to 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, spree

I have a ruby on rails shopping site project built using spree 2.2.6 and I want to migrate to spree 3.0.0 but I am getting tons of errors related to configuration settings. Has anyone done this before successfully or does anyone know how to achieve this?

Versions I am using:

Ruby: 2.1.1
Rails: 4.0.10
Spree: 2.2.6

I am also using compatible versions of other gems like:

```
'spree_gateway', 
'spree_auth_devise',
'spree_i18n',
'spree_recently_viewed',
'spree_tax_cloud', 
'spree_gift_card'
```

Some of these can be upgraded while some can't be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From https://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes/spree_3_0_0.html
looks pretty simple, looks like you just upgrade to rails 4.2 (probably the step you're missing. Then upgrade the gems in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Run `bundle update spree`.

Copy over the migrations from Spree (and any other engine) and run them using these commands:

```
rake railties:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

Looks as though your configuration settings issues could be related to:

> Previously payment methods and google analytics trackers could be
>   assigned an environment, such as, production/staging/development etc..
>   This is no longer the case. If you previously relied on importing data
>   from production to a development or staging environment you should
>   ensure to sanitize and/or update these credentials to prevent
>   submitting payments or analytics information to your production
>   account credentials.
>
> We recommend that you begin to manage your credentials with
>   environment variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Spree upgrades from version 2.2.6 to 3.0.0 will have to be done incrementally; with the following being the recommended way:

- Upgrade from 2.2.x to 2.3.x following steps at https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/upgrades/two-dot-two-to-two-dot-three.html
- Upgrade from 2.3.x to 2.4.x following steps at https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/upgrades/two-dot-three-to-two-dot-four.html
- Upgrade from 2.4.x to 3.0.0 following steps at https://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes/spree_3_0_0.html#upgrade-tips